# Perl regular expression {} quantifier multiple matches

Tags: regex, perl

Im trying to parse a file wherein each line has 3 floats(1, +1.0 -1.0 being valid values) and while the regular expression in the snippet matches a float value, I'm not sure how I should be using the Perl quantifier {n} to match multiple floats within a single line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $fh, "<", "floatNumbers.txt") or die "Cannot open < floatNumbers.txt";

while(<$fh>)
{
  if ($_=~m/([-+]?\d*[\.[0-9]*]?\s*)/)
  {
    print $1."\n";
  }
}
```

Code snippet, I tried to match 3 floats within a line. Could readers help me with the correct usage of the {} quantifier?

```
  if ($_=~m/([-+]?\d*[\.[0-9]*]?\s*){3}/)
```

Comment: Some questions. Does each line have only 3 values? Are they separated with delimeters? What do define as a float? Show some complete samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to do extraction and validation at the same time. I'd go with:

```
sub is_float {
   return $_[0] =~ /
      ^
      [-+]?
      (?: \d+(?:\.[0-9]*)?  # 9, 9., 9.9
      |         \.[0-9]+    # .9
      )
      \z
   /x;
}

while (<$fh>) {
   my @fields = split;

   if (@fields != 3 || grep { !is_float($_) } @fields) {
      warn("Syntax error at line $.\n");
      next;
   }

   print("@fields\n");
}
```

Note that your validation consdered `.`, `[` and `...0...0...` to be numbers. I fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

Quntifiers just allow you to specify how many times you want to match something in a regex.

For example `/(ba){3}/` would match `ba` in a string *exactly* 3 times :

bababanfnfd = `bababa` but not

baba = no match.

You can also use (taken from: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html):

- a? = match 'a' 1 or 0 times
- a* = match 'a' 0 or more times, i.e., any number of times
- a+ = match 'a' 1 or more times, i.e., at least once
- a{n,m} = match at least n times, but not more than m times.
- a{n,} = match at least n or more times
- a{n} = match exactly n times

Answer (score 1):

This is a generalized pattern that I think does what you are talking about:

```
 #  ^\s*(?:[-+]?(?=[^\s\d]*\d)\d*\.?\d*(?:\s+|$)){3}$

 ^                         # BOL
 \s*                       # optional whitespaces
 (?:                       # Grouping start
      [-+]?                     # optional -+
      (?= [^\s\d]* \d )         # lookahead for \d
      \d* \.? \d*               # match this form (everything optional but guaranteed a \d)
      (?: \s+ | $ )             # whitespaces or EOL
 ){3}                      # Grouping end, do 3 times
 $                         # EOL
```